# NodeJs add character after some series of strings

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I will get the json data as

```
{
 "url": "some url",
 "name": "name"
}
{
 "url": "some url1",
 "name": "name1"
}
```

i want to add ',' after each object in node js

Comment: Is that the exact response that you get? That's not  a valid json string!

Comment: i am not getting it as json that is my problem i want to add ',' at the endding of the each object @Vohuman

Comment: So why did you write that "I will get the json data as..."? Post the exact structure that you are getting. Is that a response to an ajax request?

Comment: *BUT IF IT'S NOT VALID JSON SYNTAX, THEN IT'S NOT A JAVASCRIPT OBJECT*!  It's just a plain, old string.  And of course you can modify strings using the standard Javascript string functions, like [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and Javascript [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding something like:

```
var json = ''; // the JSON var here
var all  = [];

    all.push(JSON.stringify(json));

var json2 = '';

    all.push(JSON.stringify(json2));

// you get the gist ..

// then, lets join them all and then turn them back into json..

var together = '[' + all.join(',') + ']';
var finalJSON = JSON.parse(together);
```

of course, you would probably use a `for` loop to loop through all the `JSON`, but the above is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the OP to mean that the input is a string.  To insert commas between braces, use replace:

```
var withCommas = string.replace(new RegExp('}\s*{'), '},{');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply using the replace method with a regex to get the result you're looking for. So your code will look like this:

```
json.replace(/}/g, '},'); // replace all `}` with `},`
```

Where the `json` variable is obviously your JSON string.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

"I will get the json data as..."
  <= No!  Your example is NOT valid JSON!!!!

"i want to add ',' after each object in node js..."
  <= You don't have *any* valid Javascript options, and you can't add "," to an object, even if you had one!!!

This is an object - an array object, with two items:

EXAMPLE (Javascript/JSON array):

```
[
  {
   "url": "some url",
   "name": "name"
  },
  {
   "url": "some url1",
   "name": "name1"
  }
]
```

SUGGESTION:

I'm a big fan of http://jsoneditoronline.org- I believe you might find it helpful!

Comment: I think the OP aims to turn a JSON-ish string into JSON, with a critical (but not only, as you point out) step being the insertion of commas.